# component rendering inside parent component

Tags: angular

I have created a multi-step wizard component and i need to render this multi-step wizard inside another component. Like when a user clicks the menu tab item then inside that i want to display the wizard. Generally when we develop a angular project app.component.ts will generate one component then we can place the component inside the index.html page so the component is going to display properly. But here my hierarchy is i want to display it on the menu item page. So any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

See the image for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply, insert your wizard component selector inside your menu item component template. if app-wizard is your component selector, Then simply put

```
<app-wizard></app-wizard>
```

inside menu item templete

Comment: Not in the menu item but when i click on the menu item say for example Profile then the corresponding Profile page is going to open so inside that profile page i need to place some multi step wizard.

Comment: that's what i was saying. inside your profile page template. insert selector of the wizard component